# Kernel keeps restarting in the same spot in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, kernel, jupyter-notebook

My entire Jupyter Notebook runs fine until my very last piece of code which is:

```
from gensim.summarization import keywords
print ('Keywords:')
print (keywords(All_questions, words=10))
```

I am pretty sure it's giving me it is not working because this is a computationally expensive task, since there are 400K rows of data.

After hours of running that code in Jupyter it gives me a message "The kernel appears to have died and will restart". I have tried rerunning the notebook a few times and it always gets stuck at this line.

What should I do? Thanks!